# How to converting by using "Table to Structed Grid" on Paraview?

Tags: csv, data-visualization, paraview

I tried converting a *CSV file* to Structured Grid.

Arrays in the file are `X==size 16`, `Y==size 16`, `Z==size 24`.

Unfortunately, defective result was returned. Many points are lacking, and volume rendering was failed.

But result of `Filters/ Alphabetical/ Table To Points` is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your data is really a grid (that is to say that you have the coordinates of each point at the grid nodes), that you select the correct order for x,y,z (x should be the one the "changes fastest") and to set the extent correctly (from 0  to dimension-1)

For example, if your csv file should looks like:

```
X,Y,Z
0,0,0
1,0,0
0,1,0
1,1,0
0,0,1
1,0,1
0,1,1
1,1,1
```

you have to set the extent 0-1,0-1,0-1